# JPA equivalent for Hibernate NamedQuery's setCharacter(..), setDate(..) etc...?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to set Date and Character in JPA. There are special methods in Hibernate as below:

```
Query q = session.getNamedQuery(namedQuery);
q.setDate(0, (Date) (params[i]));
q.setCharacter(1, params[i]);
q.executeUpdate();
```

Is there anything in JPA as `setCharacter()`?

I know there is `setParameter()` with `Date` but I do not know how to do it with `Character`. I want to convert it into JPA query parameter like:

```
Query q = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(namedQuery);
// How to set Date and Character in JPA ?
...
q.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: If you have a parameter that is a Character then you call `setParameter` and pass a Character in!

Comment: @DN1 but it takes as object using `setParameter`

Comment: and a Character is an Object ...

Comment: Ya but i have to differentiate it in to string,Date or Char using condition..

Comment: No idea what you mean by "differentiate it". If the query takes a String pass a String, if it takes a Character pass a Character, etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment:

> Ya but i have to differentiate it in to string,Date or Char using condition..

No, you do not have to *differentiate*. Assuming you are using [jpa](/questions/tagged/jpa) named query you just use `setParam(..)`. Suppose you have named query like:

```
@NamedQuery(name="DateCharacter.findOlderByChar",
        query="SELECT dc FROM DateCharacter dc "
             +"WHERE dc.date<:date AND dc.character=:character")
```

Setting params goes then like:

```
Query query = em.createNamedQuery("DateCharacter.findOlderByChar");
query.setParameter("date", new Date());
query.setParameter("character", 'a');
```

If you then need casting, do it on `setParam(..)` like:

```
query.setParameter("character", (char)97); // ascii code for 'a'
```

And if you need any *conditions* to determine how to cast do it before setting the parameter.

But if you try to put a wrong type of param like string for character:

```
query.setParameter("character", "a string");
```

you will end up with an exception like:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot convert object "a string" of type "class java.lang.String" into an instance of "class java.lang.Character".